# What is tightness in $C$-space

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a sequence of stochastic process $X_n(t)$, what's the meaning of $X_n(t)$ is $C$-tight?($C$ is the space of continuous functions).It seems means that $X_n(t)$ is taking values in $C$ and the sequence is tight.  But the sample paths of $X_n(t)$ is in $C$, and $X_n(t)$ is taking values in real line, then how can we say that $X_n(t)$ is tight in $C$-space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may think of each $X_n$ as a map from your sample space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ to $C$.  As an exercise, you may prove it is measurable (equip $C$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra).  Saying "$X_n$ is $C$-tight" presumably means what you would expect: for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a compact $K \subset C$ such that $P(X_n \in K) > 1-\epsilon$ for all $n$.  By Prohorov's theorem, a consequence of this would be that there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ converging weakly.